# Microsoft Excel dropdownlist gone after save?

Tags: c#, excel

```
Sheet.get_Range(
"D2", 
string.Format("D{0}", MAX_ROWS)).Validation
    .Add(E.XlDVType.xlValidateList, 
         Type.Missing, 
         E.XlFormatConditionOperator.xlBetween, 
         string.Join(",", CountryCollection.Select(x=>x.CountryName.Replace(",",")).ToArray()));
```

The above code will helps to generate a drop down list on a newly opened excel file but once the user save sheet, the dropdownlist will be gone. Changes that user made will remain there but the drop down list will be dissapear. Any idea?

**UPDATES:**

Currently suspecting the reason that the dropdownlist has gone is due to the below code

```
void WB_BeforeSave(bool SaveAsUI, ref bool Cancel)
{
    workSheet.get_Range(START_CELL, string.Format(END_CELL, MAX_ROWS)).Validation.Delete();
}
```

I've tried commented out the above code so that the validation would not be deleted however, when I try to open the excel sheet manually, Microsoft Excel detects that the validation are unreadable content and it deletes it automatically.

Comment: You should provide more source code to help people identify the problem.

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE]

Comment: also share which excel library you are using

Comment: @Patel I'm using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`

Answer (score 0):

Try saving excel in `.xlsx` format , some behaviours will not take effect if correct file format is not selected.

Comment: Yes, if I create a dropdownlist manually via `validation` method and save them manually, the dropdownlist will be maintained and accessible.